# how to reload nginx - systemctl or nginx -s?

Tags: linux, nginx, systemd

Is there a difference between calling

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

and calling

```
nginx -s reload
```

?

I know that, besides systemd, there are other init systems like SysV and Upstart. So maybe this question applies to them too.

Is it preferable to issue this command through the init system or can I just call nginx itself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually if your system supports it, I would prefer using `service` or `init.d`, like `sudo service nginx reload`

Comment: [If the system uses systemd](https://superuser.com/a/1777162/260929) then `systemctl` should be used, not the older `service` or `init.d`. In some cases `service` is just a script that uses `systemctl`, and `init.d` doesn't exist. (For example that's how it is on an Amazon Linux 2 system I have.)

Comment: (That's true in general, but in this specific case, `systemctl` should only be used *if* the init system is used to reload nginx, instead of `nginx -s reload`, which seems to have its pros and cons.)

Answer (score 33):

You can find out what `systemd reload nginx` will do by looking at the `ExecReload=` option in the `[Service]` section in the `nginx.service` unit file (located at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` on my system):

```
$ systemctl cat nginx | grep ExecReload=
```

Or by running:

```
$ systemctl show nginx.service --property=ExecReload
```

On my system, I get:

```
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

From `nginx(8)`:

```
-s signal      Send a signal to the master process. The argument signal
               can be one of: stop, quit, reopen, reload. The following
               table shows the corresponding system signals:

               stop    SIGTERM
               quit    SIGQUIT
               reopen  SIGUSR1
               reload  SIGHUP
```

Thus `systemctl reload nginx` and `nginx -s reload` will, **almost**, do the same thing.

The differences are:

- `systemctl reload nginx` will execute the command in a clean environment (and not the current user environment);
- `systemctl reload` works for any service that allows it (which has it configured in the unit file). No need to remember service specific commands. This is even more interesting if you have several instances of a service.

Using `service` or `init.d` scripts are legacy/deprecated ways of doing the same thing. Although they might work, they are not supported nor recommended anymore on a systemd based system.

Comment: The OP seems to have not been here for a long time, but I think answer deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is a difference on Centos 7 and RHEL 7. Using systemctl reload nginx will NOT validate your configuration.

See the following bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1565377

So I would advise using nginx -s reload or updating your nginx unit file to use the following reload command:

```
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1419614&action=diff

Comment: Thanks for this excellent tip. `service nginx reload` used to not only prevent reloading if errors exist, it would display the errors... systemctl reload nginx must be followed by systemctl status nginx for the same effect. Any idea if error reporting can also be achieved via ExecReload?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `nginx -s reload`. On Centos8 `systemctl reload nginx` does `/bin/kill -s HUP $mainpid`, so if there are any errors in configuration it doesn't provide you any information (you will need to go look at the nginx `error.log` file to see where the error is). `nginx -s reload` will print errors to the console, which I find more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

We had no success with `systemctl`. However, in order to reload an nginx config you can send `HUP` to the master process[1]. We just use `killall` (no it doesn't kill, it sends a signal) to send `HUP` to all nginx processes. I assume the workers just ignore the HUP:

```
sudo killall -s HUP nginx
```

Voila! The new config is loaded and applied.

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Comment: Another answer (https://superuser.com/a/1323873/260929) noted that sending the signal with `kill` will not validate configuration, while `nginx -s reload` will. So if `nginx -s reload` seems to work then it's preferable. (And as other answers describe, `systemctl reload nginx` may run `nginx -s reload`.)