# How to know if I am using systemd on Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, systemd, init

How could I know if my linux starts with `systemd` or whatever package?

Comment: on rpm distros, `rpm --quiet --query systemd`. this avoids the hanky panky involved in looking for a process or pid or symlink.

Comment: also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but since I was just asking myself the same question - here are my 2ct.

### Best solution I came up with

```
ps --no-headers -o comm 1
```

This returns either `systemd` or `init` and appears reliable across Linux distributions and releases.

`file /sbin/init` would work, with help of pattern matching. Output of `ps 1` does not appear helpful since on some Linux distributions it will print 'init' (the symlink) despite systemd being used.

### Debian 8

```
$ ps 1
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:02 /sbin/init
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd
```

### RHEL 7

```
$ ps 1
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     7:46 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: symbolic link to `../lib/systemd/systemd'
```

### SLES 12

```
$ ps 1
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:24 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: symbolic link to `../usr/lib/systemd/systemd'
```

### openSUSE 13.1

```
$ ps 1
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:33 /sbin/init showopts
$ /sbin/init: symbolic link to `../usr/lib/systemd/systemd'
```

Comment: THIS is the best answer!

Comment: So Microsoft is shipping Ubuntu as part of WSL 2. On it, the systemctl command isn't available, not DBus bindings of Systemd are available, but some of the solutions proposed here literally report "systemd". But even MS confirms it is not systemd they are using in their "Ubuntu". This solution actually reveals the difference. For WSL 2 Ubuntu it returns init, on real Ubuntu it returns "systemd". Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `ps --no-headers -o comm 1` doesn't work on embedded Linux builds using BusyBox as the executable implementation of `ps`. Here's the error: `ps: unrecognized option '--no-headers'
BusyBox v1.31.1 (2022-08-04 07:12:02 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: ps [-o COL1,COL2=HEADER`

Answer (score 25):

Check what process is running as PID 1.  You can do this by running `ps 1` and scrolling to the top.  If you have some systemd thing running as PID 1, you have systemd running.

Alternatively, run `systemctl` to list running systemd units.

You might also want to check what /sbin/init is; `file /sbin/init` will tell you if it's a real executable or if it's a symbolic link to some other package's executable.  On a systemd box, for example:

```
root@boxy / # file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: symbolic link to ../lib/systemd/systemd
```

For more information, check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process

Another way of seeing exactly what you have on your system is typing `man init` and seeing which program's man page you end up on.

Comment: An easier way to see what's running with pid 1 is `ps 1` (the number 1).

Comment: @deltab Thanks for clearing that up! I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: Great guys(@deltab,@dma1324)!!! My `ps 1` shows `/sbin/init`, and my `file /sbin/init` shows a binary, so I think it's not systemd. Then I have tried to run the `systemctl` command and get the "command not found" error, so now I'm sure I have not systemd on my linux.

Answer (score 12):

The **correct** solution is to check the presence of `/run/systemd/system` directory.

```sh
[[ -d /run/systemd/system ]] && echo "using systemd"
```

This method is used by systemd's own library function `sd_booted()`: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_booted.html

Comment: Using '-d' instead of '-x' would be a bit more accurate. Prevents potential confusion about an executable file vs a directory.

Comment: Updated my answer to use `-d`. I originally intended to use `-e` but got the options mixed up. These shouldn't make any difference in practice.

Comment: I prefer this instead: `[ -d /run/systemd/system ] && echo "using systemd" || echo "NOT using systemd"`

Answer (score 3):

Run `systemd-notify --booted` (or `systemctl is-system-running --quiet`) and check if it returns 0 or not.

From `systemd-notify`(1) man page:

> ```
>    --booted
>        Returns 0 if the system was booted up with systemd,
>        non-zero otherwise. If this option is passed, no
>        message is sent. This option is hence unrelated to
>        the other options. For details about the semantics
>        of this option, see sd_booted(3). An alternate way
>        to check for this state is to call systemctl(1)
>        with the is-system-running command. It will return
>        "offline" if the system was not booted with
>        systemd.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Best answer I found so far was to ask the package manager of your distro which package installed the /sbin/init file. For example, on debian-based, that would be

```
dpkg -S /sbin/init
```

If `/sbin/init` doesn't exist on your system, you can look for what program as pid 1 instead with `ps 1`.

Answer (score -2):

[@Trevor-Boyd-Smith](https://superuser.com/users/28756/trevor-boyd-smith) linked to this discussion on [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell) based on which I would like to offer:

```
[[ `systemctl` =~ -\.mount ]] || { echo 'Systemd not found'; exit 1; }
```

This bash statement will either just execute or print the message and exit the running script.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. But this works for me.