# How to find whether system uses systemd in chroot?

Tags: linux, systemd, chroot, chroot-jail

I was using the following command to check whether system uses systemd
`if [[ 1 == pidof systemd ]]; then`

But this fails in chroot since proc is not mounted.

`sh-4.2# pidof systemd
sh-4.2# ps
Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc`

What alternative method can be used to check whether system uses systemd or sysv?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: If so, the script will register the service to systemd, otherwise no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to know if I am using systemd on my linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/1017959/how-to-know-if-i-am-using-systemd-on-my-linux)

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to verify things from within the chroot environment?  How are you going to configure systemd outside the chroot, from inside it?

Comment: My intention is to enable systemd within the chroot jail (It could be another OS)

Comment: @MarkStosberg, This question is specific to chroot jail and it is mentioned in the question. It may not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if /sbin/init is a symlink to systemd. This isn't as good as the `ps` method because it's possible (but unlikely) that something besides `/sbin/init` is pid 1.

```
if [[ `file /sbin/init | grep -q systemd && echo 1` = 1 ]]
```

Comment: But this is in a chroot (see the title/tags)?  The init binary doesn't need to be in the chroot.  Or you could have an init binary, that isn't the same as the system init.

Comment: It works in my chroot environment. But not sure there are any caveats like @Zoredache said.